# Weird output of source file in C when used through header file

Tags: c, printf

I am currently mucking around writing a little dice rolling game in C and I am getting a weird error.

I have the code in a source file for the program to be run, and I've put it into the header file as well and included it in my main() function.

What happens is that if I run the dice roll program by itself as it's own program I get the correct results. as soon as I run it and link it through the header I get weird results in the hundreds, for example the output was 927 for the roll of two dice which doesn't make sense.

Code is below as follows.

**Dice.h**

```
int Roll_Dice(void); //haven't used headers a lot so i just have this placed in there.
```

**Dice_roll.c**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


int Roll_Dice(void)
{
setvbuf(stdout, 0, _IONBF, 0);
int dice1 = 0;
int dice2 = 0;
int dice_roll= 0;
int sides;
int i = 0;   
srand(time(NULL));
{
rollagain:   
printf("how many sides of the dice are there? (maximum 8)");
scanf ("%d", &sides);

        if (sides > 9)
    {
        printf("this is not a valid input, must be 8 or less\n ");

        goto rollagain;
       } else {
    dice1 = (rand() % sides) + 1; //pretty self explantory
    dice2 = (rand() % sides) + 1;
    dice_roll = dice1 + dice2;

 }

printf("the number you rolled was %d", dice_roll);
return 0; 
// tried changing this to return "dice_roll" but still got weird outputs when using it with a header.

 }


}
```

**Main.c**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include "Dice.h"


int main(void)
{
printf("%d", Roll_Dice()); simple thing to call the function, don't actually know if this is correct.
}
```

If anyone could point out why it would be giving me a weird output in the main file i would appreciate it.

Comment: what about the loop `for (i = 0; i > 0; i++);`?

Comment: `(maximum 8)` and `if (sides > 9)`.. doesn't match.

Comment: Oh possibly.... i might try ommitting that compeltly and re-doing it with just an If statement and leave the for loop out of it.

Comment: also, add `#include <stdlib.h>` in `Dice_roll.c`

Comment: `int Roll_Dice(void);` in `Dice_roll.c`...is this `;` a typo or is it there in actual code?

Comment: Compile with all warnings and debug info (`gcc -Wall -Wextra -g`). Use the debugger (`gdb`). BTW, you should test the result (item count) of [scanf(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/scanf.3.html). And your program would crash if the user inputs 0 for `sides`

Comment: You most likely want to call `srand` once in main, not every time you roll the dice.

Comment: How do i sanitise my input so that 0 is not an option?, and i will move the srand to main. see how it works. see sourav's answer below, weirdly enough putting a line break \n actually fixed the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are some points to mention.

1. include `<stdlib.h>` in `Dice_roll.c` to get the prototype for `srand()` and `rand()`
2. Get rid of the `;` in `int Roll_Dice(void);` in `Dice_roll.c`. You need to have the `;` while calling and declaring the function, not at function definition.
3. Put an additional check for `side` not to hold a value of `<=0`
4. To restrict `side` to a max value of 8, change if `(sides > 9)` to `if (sides > 8)`

Note: You may want to move the `srand(time(NULL));` into the `main()` from the `Roll_Dice()` function.

---

EDIT:

Following the infromation in below comments, the issue was the output from two successive `printf()`s printing side-by-side to make the output *appear* wrong.

Comment: ahh yep that was actually a typo when i was inputting it onto here. that semicolon doesn't exist. sorry about that.
and added #includes...but still getting the same weird output.

Comment: @LewisFletch  I'm not very sure, but I hope it's not like you're considering the output of two successive `printf()`s together, right? To avoid confusion, try to add a `\n` after `"the number you rolled was %d"` and try.

Comment: weirdly enough that fixed it.... that is the most bizarre little glitch.
thanks for that.

Comment: @LewisFletch that seperates the output of two successive prints. You're welcome.